# Flash Builder Java Heap Space Error

Tags: java, eclipse, flash-builder

I've been developing a flash application using Flash Builder 4.7 and all of a sudden it hit me with a "java Heap space" error. I've tried increasing the heap space which has no effect.

Eclipse will run but every time I try to run or debug my application it just hangs or doesn't do anything and the HTML page says "Movie Not Loaded", then every now and then it hits me with the heap space error again.

Here's my crash log:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2012-11-14 14:19:39.747
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Building workspace".
!STACK 0
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2786)
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:71)
at com.adobe.flash.swf.io.OutputBitStream.writeByte(OutputBitStream.java:230)
at com.adobe.flash.swf.io.OutputBitStream.writeSI16(OutputBitStream.java:304)
at com.adobe.flash.swf.io.OutputBitStream.writeUI16(OutputBitStream.java:355)
at com.adobe.flash.swf.io.SWFWriter.finishTag(SWFWriter.java:400)
at com.adobe.flash.swf.io.SWFWriter.writeTag(SWFWriter.java:1512)
at com.adobe.flash.swf.io.SWFWriter.writeTag(SWFWriter.java:1285)
at com.adobe.flash.swf.io.SWFWriter.writeFrames(SWFWriter.java:869)
at com.adobe.flash.swf.io.SWFWriter.writeTo(SWFWriter.java:2633)
at       com.adobe.flexbuilder.multisdk.compiler.internal.ASApplicationBuilderNext.buildSWF(ASApplicationBuilderNext.java:260)
at com.adobe.flexbuilder.multisdk.compiler.internal.ASApplicationBuilderNext.build(ASApplicationBuilderNext.java:97)
at com.adobe.flexbuilder.multisdk.compiler.internal.ASBuilderNext.build(ASBuilderNext.java:117)
at com.adobe.flexbuilder.multisdk.compiler.internal.ASItemBuilder.build(ASItemBuilder.java:93)
at com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.compiler.internal.FlexProjectBuilder.buildItem(FlexProjectBuilder.java:701)
at com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.compiler.internal.FlexProjectBuilder.build(FlexProjectBuilder.java:405)
at com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.compiler.internal.FlexIncrementalBuilder.build(FlexIncrementalBuilder.java:171)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:728)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:239)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:292)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:295)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:351)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:374)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:143)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:241)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2012-11-14 14:19:45.181
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Launching NotNormalCampaignApp".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.getLaunchManager(LaunchConfiguration.jav a:462)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:858)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:703)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:928)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1132)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Here's my ini file

```
-startup
../../../eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
    ../../../eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110502
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
../../../assets/fb_splash_premium.png
-nl
en_US
-vmargs
-Xmn256m
-Xms512m
-Xmx768m
-XX:MaxPermSize=384m
-XX:PermSize=128m
-XX:+UseParNewGC
-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-Xdock:name=Flash Builder
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/fb_app.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-Declipse.product=com.adobe.flexbuilder.standalone.producte36
-Declipse.application=com.adobe.flexbuilder.standalone.FlashBuilderApplication
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

I've run out of ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: You should probably post your .ini file as well so we know what values you are setting.

Comment: Also I should add, I created a new project and that compiles fine so it is project specific.

Comment: The new project is empty or did you port the current's content to it? If it's a clean project, you are running out of heap memory out of your program's size, or because of a memory-leak flaw. If it's size, increasing the heap memory with `-xmx1024m` will solve the problem. If not, doing so will make the problem vanish also, but it will just mask the problem (Don't mask problems! Fix them!), and for a proper fix, you will have to debug your code, find the leak, and fix it.